# Не работает анимация для RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Создал файл анимации:

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="-20%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="0"/>

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1"/>

<scale
    android:fromXScale="200%"
    android:fromYScale="200%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="100%"
    android:toYScale="100%"/>
```

Создал файл аниматора:

```
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:animation="@anim/register_message_item_animation"
                 android:animationOrder="normal"
                 android:delay="15%"/>
```

Объявил аниматор в ресайклере:

```
//...
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/registerRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fill_down"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pickerHolder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/registerToolbar"
        tools:listitem="@layout/register_message_bot_item"/>
//...
```

При обновлении списка пользуюсь `DiffUtill` внутри `RecyclerView.Adapter`.
Каждый раз когда пушу новый список, при добавлении нового айтема не происходит анимация - в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А где вы прописываете `duration`?)

Comment: Ни где, duration используется дефолтный в случае его отсутсвия